# AWS Beanstalk, deploy app via Azure Devops to IIS Default Website but not to a child application

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure-devops, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, umbraco8

I am attempting to deploy a Umbraco 8 site to AWS Beanstalk via Azure Devops to IIS.  I have a release pipeline in place that has a **Deploy to Elastic Beanstalk Application Action** which works and I can see my app deployed.

the Elastic Beanstalk Application Action is part of the AWS Toolkit for Azure Dev Ops https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vsts/latest/userguide/elastic-beanstalk-deploy.html

The issue i seem to have is instead of deploying to the default web site directly a child application is being created and the app is being deployed there which has a knock on effect of causing some of the Umbraco urls resolutions to fail for some reason.

Is there a way of forcing the deployment to actually deploy directly to the default web application rather then to a child application?

Comment: Does your archive sent to AWS include extra folder path information that it should not?  If your zip has something like `\deployable\file.cs` it will be added to the server in a "deployable" sub-folder not into the www root.  At least that's the behavior for a PHP app.

Comment: Devops nests the artifact so there are a lot of sub folders, it creates a stucture like this Content\D_C\a\1\s\src\AppName.Web\obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp and then creates a child application called AppName_Web.  This is standard Devops artifact generation

Comment: For our PHP app, we zip with relative paths instead of absolute paths, starting in the folder that we want to be the www root.  We aren't using Azure or IIS so I can't offer suggestions for those other than mentioning the paths issue.

Comment: Source code for `Deploy to Elastic Beanstalk Application Action`? Where is this from?

Comment: There is no source code @ErmiyaEskandary its a devops step that is part of the AWS Toolkit for Azure Devops https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vsts/latest/userguide/elastic-beanstalk-deploy.html

Comment: OK thanks, I wanted to confirm - please add that info to the question.